# Sum Rows Value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I need sum values of differents columns by a criteria.
Now, I have this df:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `index(I renamed it to name for clarity, you can group on index) and date(if grouping on index, set date as index)` and then apply `sum` function over it.

**Input**

```
d="""date,Val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7
01-02-2021,0,1,3,5,0,0,0
01-02-2021,1,0,0,5,1,4,5
01-02-2021,0,0,2,0,5,0,0
01-02-2021,0,1,3,5,0,0,0
01-02-2021,1,0,0,5,1,4,5
01-02-2021,0,0,2,0,5,0,0"""
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
df.index = ['Juan', 'Juan', 'Juan','Pedro','John','John']
df
```

**Input DF**

```
        date    Val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7
Juan    01-02-2021  0   1   3   5   0   0   0
Juan    01-02-2021  1   0   0   5   1   4   5
Juan    01-02-2021  0   0   2   0   5   0   0
Pedro   01-02-2021  0   1   3   5   0   0   0
John    01-02-2021  1   0   0   5   1   4   5
John    01-02-2021  0   0   2   0   5   0   0
```

**Code**

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'name'})
df.groupby(['name', 'date'], sort=False).sum().reset_index(level=1).rename_axis(None)
```

**Output**

```
        date        Val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7
Juan    01-02-2021  1       1       5       10  6   4   5
Pedro   01-02-2021  0       1       3       5   0   0   0
John    01-02-2021  1       0       2       5   6   4   5
```

**If date is not required in output**

```
df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum()
```

**Output**

```
       Val1 val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7
Juan    1   1   5   10  6   4   5
Pedro   0   1   3   5   0   0   0
John    1   0   2   5   6   4   5
```

Comment: I am trying with your code, but it does not work: 
df = db_merge.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'name'})
df = df.groupby(['NOMBRE', 'FECHA'], sort=False).sum().reset_index(level=1).rename_axis(None)

Comment: There is not error, it just doesn't work. The rows continue to appear with 0 instead of sum them according to the date and the name

Comment: Is the first column with names is index in your df or is it a column?

Comment: I have added the input df I have considered.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) per first and second level:

```
df.set_index('Date', append=True).sum(level=[0, 1]).reset_index(level=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `melt()` and `pivot_table()` method:

```
df=(df.melt(id_vars=['index','date'])
    .pivot_table(index=['index','date'],columns='variable',values='value',aggfunc='sum'))
```

Output of `df`:

```
         variable   Val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7
index   date                            
John    01-02-2021  1       0       2       5       6       4       5
Juan    01-02-2021  1       1       5       10      6       4       5
Pedro   01-02-2021  0       1       3       5       0       0       0
```